# Редирект в NGINX в сохранением get-параметра

Tags: nginx, редирект

На сайте изменились адрес фида.
было:

```
/rss/feed.xml?psid=34016
```

стало:

```
/rss.xml?psid=34016
```

в параметр psid передаются разные значения, он не постоянен.

Прошу помочь с редиректом на nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /rss/ {
    return 301 /rss.xml$is_args$args;
}
```

В случае если в обработчике указан `return` nginx завершает обработку и возвращает клиенту указанный код. Для кодов 301, 302, 303, 307 и 308 можно задать либо URL перенаправления, либо текст тела ответа (для остальных кодов). В тексте тела ответа и URL перенаправления можно использовать переменные. Как частный случай, URL перенаправления может быть задан как URI, локальный для данного сервера, при этом полный URL перенаправления формируется согласно схеме запроса (`$scheme`) и директивам `server_name_in_redirect` и `port_in_redirect`.

Документация, в которой всё написано, [тут](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).

Comment: **norbornen** огромное Вам спасибо!